# React HOC Generic Type P is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & P & { children?: ReactNode; }'

Tags: typescript

I am currently in the process of upgrading typescript from 4.7.4 to 5.2.2 and have run into the following error:

> Type error: Type 'P' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & P & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
> Type 'P' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.

I have a react HOC called withErrorBoundary that I wrap components in. For example

```
interface Props {
  name: string;
}

const ComponentA = ({name}: Props): JSX.Element => {
  return <div>{name}</div>;
}   

export default withErrorBoundary(ComponentA);
```

The HOC code is

```
export const withErrorBoundary = <P, >(WrappedComponent: ComponentType<P>): ComponentClass<P, ErrorBoundaryState> => (
    class extends Component<P, ErrorBoundaryState> {
        static contextType = ErrorContext;
        declare context: ContextType<typeof ErrorContext>;

        constructor(props: P) {
            super(props);
            this.state = { error: null, errorInfo: null };
        }

        componentDidCatch = (error: Error, errorInfo: ErrorInfo): void => {
            // ...
        };

        componentWillUnmount(): void {
           // ...
        }

        render(): JSX.Element {
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props as P} />;
        }
    }
);
```

What is the cause of the issue and how to fix it?